# How to restrict android app to connect to specific wifi & work only in that particular wifi premises

Tags: android, authentication, wifi, android-wifi, wifimanager

I am working on a project for a client which has some premises at different location on the globe.

How do I restrict my android application to work on a specific wifi network of a specific premises.

For Example Let A and B be the two separate authorized premises on different overseas location.These premises have their own wifi network and server.And these premises servers are in sync to the centralized cloud server which have a web application and database.

Now if a user X comes to any of the location, then the application can be connected to the that wifi,activated and should work their.

But if the same user tries it from outside from any unspecified place like other premises or home,etc.The application should not work from their or connect to our cloud servers any how.

So how can I restrict my application to work only on specific authorized wifi or premises.

Please provide some solution....

Can I create the centralized database of all wifi details like MAC id,SSID,etc.and match it every time the app starts.
But it has some drawbacks if that wifi has no internet connectivity, then how could I check the authenticity of that connectivity or location of the user.

Comment: i approve of this question that is for sure

Comment: I am using BSSID to detect.

Comment: Is this possible through device administration api ?